# Why is the title font in my Windows 10 programs enormous?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Recently, the title bar on my Windows 10 programs has been displaying in a larger font size.  For example, if I fire up Notepad, it looks like this:

[image: Notepad using a gigantic font in the title bar...]

Where it says "Untitled - Notepad," the font is MUCH larger than what I'm used to.  Any idea why?

Looking through my Display settings, the only thing I notice is that I have everything scaled by 250%.  But that is the recommended setting for my monitor resolution, and it's been that way for a long time.

Thanks for any suggestions!

UPDATE: I tried turning off the 250% magnification.  Everything got smaller, but the title text is still much larger than usual -- basically a scaled down version of my earlier screenshot.

[image]

Comment: " I have everything scaled by 250%." that is the reason.

Comment: Open Start, Settings, System,  and in the Search box enter Make Text Bigger.   See if this setting has been set too large. That may be why you see bigger fonts.

Comment: I had the same issue just now, but after restarting my PC it was fixed again.

Comment: I have everything scaled to 100% and the huge font issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the title bar height and width. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` registry key. And now change the value of `CaptionHeight` and `CaptionWidth` values. Their values will be in this formula `-15*pixels`.

Then sign out/in or reboot. Restarting explorer.exe is not enough.

Hope that helps

Comment: Do I need to do anything special to apply these changes?  My CaptionHeight was "-330".  I changed it to "-15*pixels" and closed Regedit.  When I relaunch Notepad (or anything else), the title size is unchanged.

Comment: No multiply -15 with the desired number of pixels!

Comment: Ah, sorry, that makes sense!  However, I tried entering "-150" (for example) and saw no difference.  Must be something else...

Comment: I think this answer is basically correct, so I have accepted it.  It turned out that I had to log out and back in for the setting to apply.  In the end, I downloaded a tool called System Font Size Changer (https://www.wintools.info/index.php/system-font-size-changer) to get it to work, though.

Comment: I have the same issue. When I log out and back in, the issue is solved for a while. I just realized that the CaptionHeight & Width was -330 when the titles were huge and after the logout/login the number is now -336 and all looks fine. I'll continue to monitor this.

Comment: Thanks @gdelfino! In my case the value was -330 also, and I had this huge title font. I first changed it to -165, which was good to solve the title fonts size. However, I noted that after this change, icons in the notification area had a reduced size as well. After changing CaptionHeight & Width to -336 all looks fine now. It seems that the formula "-15*pixels" is not valid for all pixel values.

Comment: This did not work for me.  The only effect was to render the icones in the system tray extremely small.  No title bars were affected at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these registry values to fix the problem.

windowmetrics.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"BorderWidth"="-15"
"CaptionFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"CaptionHeight"="-330"
"CaptionWidth"="-330"
"IconFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"IconTitleWrap"="1"
"MenuFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuHeight"="-285"
"MenuWidth"="-285"
"MessageFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ScrollHeight"="-255"
"ScrollWidth"="-255"
"Shell Icon Size"="32"
"SmCaptionFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SmCaptionHeight"="-330"
"SmCaptionWidth"="-330"
"StatusFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"PaddedBorderWidth"="-60"
"AppliedDPI"=dword:00000060
"IconSpacing"="-1125"
"IconVerticalSpacing"="-1125"
"MinAnimate"="1"
```

I got these values by

1. creating a brand new user
2. opening regedit to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`
3. right click `WindowsMetrics` and export to a file somewhere your main user can access, like `C:\windowmetrics.reg`
4. login to your original broken user account
5. right click the .reg file and choose `Merge`
6. logout and login again

These steps just fixed the issue for me.  Windows 10 22H2 running in the Parallels VM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nothing helped. Even after freshly installing Windows 11 (switching from Windows 10), the issue still persisted sporadically on screen wake up.

I then found, so far, the only way to recover:

1. unplug the HDMI cable
2. plug the cable back in!